# Horizontal page curl animation from bottom right-ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, reader, page-curl

I'm developing an ebook App for that I'm loading XHTML content in `UIWebview`. I've disabled the horizontal scroll and changing the content offset when user swipe right/left with page curl animation. I took the code from [this](http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/how-to-implement-partial-and-full-page.html) tutorial, In this tutorial the page turn from right to left is happening from top like below.

[Note: it is not curl up but horizontal like page, I want the exact same but from bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDz4l.png)

I want the same effect but from bottom right not from up. Please don't suggest leaves I tried that already, I don't want that kind of animation.

> Note: I need Horizontal page curl (no curl up) both left to right and right to left from bottom.

Comment: Any Solutions for this, Please update.